# Spring hibernate default session management

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So I have a 3 layer application. With hibernate auto configured via spring boot starter jpa. And the config class using @EnableJpaRepositories(enttityManagerFactory, transactionManager, basepackages)

My question is, if a controller calls a service which gets entity from the DB, can the service pass that entity along to other components, without it being detached, considering its still the same thread, right?

Or is session based on each method level? maybe i need to annotate the controller @Transactional?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to annotate the controller.

Comment: I could use join fetch to fetch as much as possible and then use the transacton read only to get any many rows later on..

Comment: @user1555190 join-fetch is not enougth, you might need to call every single getter on the entities in order to have the entities read eager before you leave the service-layer because an innocent getter might require to read informations from the database. Yes the same thread is important but also important is the same connection and session and transaction. You will loose the connection, session and transaction if you leave the service-layer but remain in the same thread. Also you will not be able to compare two entities in the controller-layer using the == operator and ... (comment too long)

Comment: Long story short: Its a bad idea.